# preg_split()—Issue with Pipe Character

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split a string that is formatted like this:

> Value1==Value1||Value2==Value2||..."

at both the == and the || but I'm having trouble with the pipes. I'm able to easily split them at the == but when I try to add in the pipes it's either not working or splitting it at every character. What pattern should I be using? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`|` is a special character that should be escaped by a backslash. Use `\|+` to match one or more pipes and split on it if the number of pipes is variable, or `\|\|` to match two pipes in a regular expression.

`preg_split('/\|+/', $your_string)`

**However**, if it is *always* two pipes, this is better done with a plain old `explode("||" $your_string)`

Answer (score 2):

The pipe (`|`) has special meaning in regular expressions. Escape it with `\`.